# curl X POST command fails on win10 but succeed on MacOS/ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mac-osx

When I use

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":2.0,"params":[], "id":1,"method":"web3_clientVersion"}' 'node-ip:8545'
```

in `win10` terminal (as admin) for RPC call to retrieve API version running on a remote server, it fails with `error: {"code":-32700,"message":"parse error"}` which indicates that the JSON format provided for `--data` is not correct. However the same `curl` command works fine on both `MacOS` and `ubuntu`. Is the `curl` on win10 not created same as it is on linux? How to fix this curl problem on win10?

Comment: What was the actual command that you ran?

Comment: Just updated the post with the command.

Comment: Thi quoting looks right for a bash shell. I dunno about PowerShell or the old Windows cmd.exe though.